# oauth shopify for my external website registration

Tags: oauth, shopify

I'm using oauth to access products, customers, orders, etc in my shopify store. But I came across a particular situation. Basically I want users (store owners) to register to my site using their shopify account. Like for example in the image below, users have have option to login using facebook or google or even email. I'm looking to add 'Signup with Shopify' or something.

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried for doing the same?

Comment: I've tried google oauth but I'm asking if it's possible in shopify to let them logged in to my site using their shopify account thru oauth (shopify as oauth provider).

Comment: It's possible. Make a Shopify App, though. You'll need to let them know the scope of permissions you require for them to log into your app with their Shopify account.

Comment: @cameronHurd how to go about it? I can only see products, orders, customers permission using the shopify api.

Comment: Those are the permissions that store owners would be granting you. How you go about it depends on what you want & what your app needs.

Comment: yeah permissions that store owners would be granting to access their STORE.

Comment: @silent_coder14 were you able to figure this out? I'm also trying to do this. I would prefer to not have to require a user install the app via Shopify first